# Can List<objects> Data helpful for multi Users logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

In my project I am getting all the required data to List and using that List other functionality like

```
List1.AddRange(list.FindAll(s => s.PortfolioID == ClientList[i].PortfolioID));
```

to check data and fill a gridview.I am updating that list only when the data is saved.

It's working fine with one user. But the problem is when the users are more.
Like **User1 ,user2  logged in as administrator and Client** 
 and Administrator changed data,since user2 (Client) is getting data when he logged in, he can't get the changes which admin has changed recently until he saved data or relogged in.

I have used this concept in entire project.

To do better functionality, I have two ideas:

1. Getting List in Load event.such that for evry operation it
   will get entire list of data
2. Changing  entire code to take directly from Database instead of from
   List.

I thought first one is good but I am not sure how much data can WCF services can handle. If the data is more, then there will be a problem for entire functionality. If WCF can handle more data i will use first one.

For the second one, I have to go to server for every functionality.

I am new to WCF and ASP. I need your help.
Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF services can handle more data than your users can handle, so I would use WCF and your option 1.